# VBA: Checkbox in Userform - Should be simple but not working

Tags: excel, checkbox, foreach, userform, vba

I am new to Visual Basics (2 days so far), and the only other programming I've done is MATlab.

I am trying to have the program print different numbers in different columns in Excel, depending if a checkbox in a userform is checked or not. There are 26 checkboxes in total - along with some textboxes - and I'm trying to use a For Each Control loop to run through all the checkboxes.

I've looked up a few tutorials and some forums, but when I try to run a test, the code doesn't work. More specifically, no errors show up but the "Testing if it Works?" is not printed anywhere.

```
 Private Sub Add_Button_Click()

 Dim Ctrl As Control

 For Each Ctrl In DataInput.Controls
        If TypeName(Ctrl) = "Checkbox" Then
            If Ctrl.Value = True Then
                Sheets("Data").Range("A1") = "Testing if it Works?" 
            End If
        End If
 Next

 End Sub
```

I've followed the same setup as all the other forums or tutorials I've come across, but nothing seems to be happening. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Regardless the below answer I think the only problem with you code is to change one `if statement` to this: `If TypeName(Ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then`. `If statement` is case sensitive...

Comment: KazJaw is probably right, I actually missed that this was being done in a user form. I was putting the controls outside of a user form, which made it different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: This answer only applies when putting checkboxes directly on the Excel sheets, not in a user form as was asked. Feel free to downvote!

I played around with it and it was not entirely simple at all. It's a bit different whether you're using Form controls or ActiveX controls. The code below works for me, though I'm not entirely sure they're the best ways.

With ActiveX controls:

```
Private Sub Add_Button_Click()

For Each Ctrl In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
   If TypeName(Ctrl.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
       If Ctrl.Object = True Then
           Sheets("Data").Range("A1") = "Testing if it Works?"
       End If
   End If
Next

End Sub
```

With Form controls

```
Private Sub Add_Button_Click2()

For Each Item In Me.Shapes
   If Item.FormControlType = xlCheckBox Then
       If Item.DrawingObject = 1 Then
           Sheets("Data").Range("A1") = "Testing if it Works?"
       End If
   End If
Next

End Sub
```